# Excel: Using text from a cell as the name of a worksheet in a conditional formatting equation

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

The title really does express entirely what I'm trying to do, but it's a bit convoluted and arcane, so I will explain with a use case:

If I have an excel workbook with two sheets (SheetA and SheetB) which are very close to each other, and I would like differences to visually highlight themselves, a typical way to do this might be something like this:

- In SheetA, highlight all cells
- Enter conditional formatting, New Rule, Use formula
- In the formula box enter:

  > =a1<>SheetB!a1
- apply the desired formatting and hit 'OK'

Basically what this does is compare every cell of SheetA with its counterpart in SheetB, and if they are unequal, apply the formatting.  If the sheet names are complex (especially if they contain spaces and therefore need quotes) clicking on the tab name during the formula entry does helpful things.

But now assume that *in some cell of SheetA,* I have entered a text expression containing the name of SheetB, and I would like to reference that cell in the conditional formatting formula above.

(Why?  I might have 100 spreadsheets and would like to compare 1 to 2, then 1 to 3, then 1 to 55, by changing the text in the cell, rather than manually changing the conditional formatting each time.)

How can I do that?

I am aware that the INDIRECT function is used to turn text into sheet names and have tried multiple variations on that theme, using he INDIRECT function as part of the conditional format formula, but nothing seems to really work.

Comment: your question is more than rocket science,, you are trying to compare the entire workbook followed by highlights, as you have written, "would like to compare 1 to 2, then 1 to 3, then 1 to 55" !!. Better you think for Track Changes command, this will help you lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional format formula like this:

```
= A1 <> INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1), COLUMN(A1),,, aSheet), TRUE)
```

Replace `aSheet` with a reference to the cell where you've stored the name of the sheet to compare.

The [`ADDRESS()`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) function assembles a cell reference as a text string, using the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions to work out the row and column of the cell being evaluated.

You could skip the `ADDRESS()` function and just build the cell reference in R1C1 format using string concatenation, but the formula above is probably easier to read and understand.  The equivalent would be:

```
= A1 <> INDIRECT(aSheet & "!R" & ROW(A1) & "C" & COLUMN(A1), FALSE)
```